# I am unable to retrieve data from my mongodb collection and show it to my html page

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, meteor

I am beginner in METEOR. I am unable to retrieve data and show it to my html page. I have a collection named as "login". Kindly help me in as simple language as you can. Following is my code.

Main.html

```
   <head>
   <title>Time-Bank</title>
   </head>

   <body>
     <div class="bg-color">
      {{> header}}
      {{> form}}
      {{> todos}}
     </div>
   </body>
```

Templates.html

```
    <template name="todos">
     <ul class="collection">
      {{#each todoList}}
   <b>  {{this.username}}</b>
     {{/each}}
     </ul>
    </template>
```

Helpers.js

```
     Template.todos.helpers({
     todoList:function(){
     return Collections.Login.find({});
   }
  });
```

global.js

```
  Collections = {};

  Collections.Login = new Mongo.Collection("login");
```

Comment: `return Collections.Login.find({}).fetch()`. Otherwise it's a "cursor" and not an `Array` of results like you are expecting.

Comment: This .fetch is also not working.